# PHP change file format

Tags: php, file, format

My image file format is stored as below in mongo db,

```
 "image_val": "[\"\\/attachments\\/seonotes\\/357\\/selection_007-1498621634.png\"]"
```

I fetched the value from the table and taken into a variable,

```
$image_val = "[\"\\/attachments\\/seonotes\\/357\\/selection_007-1498621634.png\"]";
```

May I get the $image_val as below (remove brackets and slashes),

```
/attachments/seonotes/357/selection_007-1498621634.png
```

Comment: and which is your question?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

You can use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes) and [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$image_val = "[\"\\/attachments\\/seonotes\\/357\\/selection_007-1498621634.png\"]";
echo str_replace(array( '["', '"]' ), '', stripslashes($image_val));
```

[`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes): Removes slashes

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace): Replace `["` and `"]` from the resultant string

---

**Method 2:**

You can use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes) and [`trim`](http://php.net/trim):

```
$image_val = "[\"\\/attachments\\/seonotes\\/357\\/selection_007-1498621634.png\"]";
echo trim(stripslashes($image_val), '["]');
```

[`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes): Removes slashes

[`trim`](http://php.net/trim): Trims the brackets from beginning and ending of the string

Answer (score 0):

**Try below method:**

```
 <?php
    echo str_replace("\\","","[\"\\/attachments\\/seonotes\\/357\\/selection_007-1498621634.png\"]");
    ?>
```

**or**

```
<?php
  echo str_replace(array( '["', '"]', '\\' ),"","[\"\\/attachments\\/seonotes\\/357\\/selection_007-1498621634.png\"]");
?>
```